# Difficult PHP String Function

Tags: php, regex, string

I have this string (98)

```
1994 Acura Integra Type R OEM B18C5 OEM Tranny All Stock Interior. 165,000 MI $9500 (000) 000-1696
```

**I need to break it at string position 57.**

**My intention is find the first occurrence of a space character (regex `\s`) going backward from pos 57.**

Then break the string there, so the string would split like this:

```
1994 Acura Integra Type R OEM B18C5 OEM Tranny All Stock // str1
Interior. 165,000 MI $9500 (000) 000-1696                // str2
```

I have tried multiple ways and can't seem to solve it:

```
$charAt58 = substr($content, 57, 1);

$hasWhiteSpaceAt58 = preg_match('/\s/', $charAt58);

if (!$hasWhiteSpaceAt58) {
    echo "false"; 
    $contentr = strrev($content);
    echo "<br>";
    echo strpos($contentr, " ", 57);
}
```

Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately maybe the string did not break at interior but that is besides the point. The point is that a word could be broken at 57, in that case I need the string split at the proper location which would be at the whitespace prior to str pos 57.

Comment: Then that position would always be this `strrpos($string, ' ', 57);`

Comment: No it wouldn't this algorithm will be implemented in a dynamic program.

Comment: `I need the string split at the proper location which would be at the whitespace prior to str pos 57.` If that is the exact description then yes it would be. Regardless of how long the string is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^.{1,57}(?=\s)
```

Try this simple regex.See demo.This will allow regex to capture untill `57` and then `backtrack` untill it finds a `space`.The lookahead will make it backtrack untill it finds space.

https://regex101.com/r/wU7sQ0/37

Comment: Hmm this seems like a promising approach. I will work with this and see how it goes with the other strings loaded dynamically.

Comment: It looks like it will, I just have to make sure before I accept the answer. But so far this looks like the answer. I will implement it in a sec and come back.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a positive lookahead and split on that.

```
\s(?=Interior)
```

The above matches only the `\s` which is followed by `Interior`

```
var_dump(preg_split("/\s(?=Interior)/", $input_line));
```

[**DEMO**](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/aeg)

Comment: have any reason for downvoting to let the answer improve or know what's wrong or just mindless downvoting?

Answer (score 0):

This one will do:

```
$pos = strrpos($content, ' ', 57);
$output = substr($content, 0, $pos) .'\n'. substr($content, $pos);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$s = '1994 Acura Integra Type R OEM B18C5 OEM Tranny All Stock Interior. 165,000 MI $9500 (000) 000-1696';
$parts = str_split($s, strrpos(substr($s, 0, 57), ' ')+1);
print_r($parts);

/*
Array
(
    [0] => 1994 Acura Integra Type R OEM B18C5 OEM Tranny All Stock
    [1] => Interior. 165,000 MI $9500 (000) 000-1696
)
*/
```